# Memoir, xelatex: how to change chaptitlefont?

Tags: xetex, memoir

I'm trying to make a chapterstyle where I use the [Intimacy](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/intimacy/) font for the name of the chapter, but I can't get it to work. I *only* want to change this, not the font of the rest of the document. Any ideas?

Here's what I want:

[image: What I'm trying to do]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\makechapterstyle{section}{%
\renewcommand{\printchaptername}{}
\renewcommand{\chapternamenum}{}
\renewcommand{\chapnumfont}{\normalfont\Huge\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\printchapternum}{\chapnumfont \thechapter\space}
\renewcommand{\afterchapternum}{}
}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Foo}
Bar
\end{document}
```

Comment: 1. Make sure you have the font installed (I don't [not in TL], so I'm using [Square Capitals](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/sqrcaps/)). 2. "renew" the commands `\chaptitlefont` and `\chapnumfont` so they include (in my case) `\sqrcfamily`. 3. Use your "section" style with `\chapterstyle{section}`.

Comment: I downloaded the .sty and it stopped complaining, but it still comes out wrong.

Comment: Fonts are usually more than just a `.sty` file. The CTAN page includes installation instructions, which you should follow.

Comment: Can you make it work with a font that's already there? I have no idea how to do that. The Intimacy font is just the icing on the cake, not the core issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have the precise font installed, but here's the basic idea:

```
\documentclass{memoir} 
\usepackage{sqrcaps} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\makechapterstyle{section}{% 
\renewcommand{\printchaptername}{} 
\renewcommand{\chapternamenum}{} 
\renewcommand{\chapnumfont}{\normalfont\Huge\sqrcfamily} 
\renewcommand{\chaptitlefont}{\normalfont\Huge\sqrcfamily}   
\renewcommand{\printchapternum}{\chapnumfont \thechapter\space} 
\renewcommand{\afterchapternum}{}  
} 
\chapterstyle{section} 
\begin{document}  
\chapter{Semper latinitas}              
Bar \texttt{foo} \textbf{bar}  \textsf{baz} 
\ldots {\sqrcfamily nunc est bibendum!}  
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! I hope the next guy/gal in need of this knowledge will find this, it's hard to figure out!